# How to implement blacklist application using MDM protocol for iOS device

Tags: ios, mdm, blacklist

We just wanna block some Apps installation or running on iOS device, we tried to use mdm protocol to implement it, but we did not find any stuff for blacklist feature. Most of MDM vendor just gave a alert/msg when they found some Apps(which are in blacklist) installation/running. Can we block it running/installation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing in MDM protocol which prevent a user from installing and running an app.

The only thing which you can do is to get a list of installed appellation through MDM and do some action (as example alerting or compliance enforcement) if you detected blacklisted app.

Comment: yes, Just like what Ronin Said，most of mdm productions just give alert or compliance enforcement

Comment: It might be possible to add a restriction that would prevent any app for being installed, but you can't be selective.